# how to fetch cursor value into varchar2 in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

help me to solve this error

29/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

29/5     PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH
         statement

**(29 is  FETCH tbsp INTO tsinfo; )**

62/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

62/5     PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH
         statement

**( 62 is  FETCH lock_info INTO lockinfo; -- i want to put database lock  result to this tsinfo)**

> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE final_package as
>
> PROCEDURE final_procedure(var1 in varchar2, dbinfo out varchar2);
>
> END final_package;
>
> /
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY final_package IS
>
> ```
>  PROCEDURE final_procedure(var1 in varchar2, dbinfo out varchar2) IS
> ```
>
> BEGIN
>
> IF var1 = 'a'
>
> ------  /* get tablespaces name, percentage */ ----
>
> THEN
>
> DECLARE
>
> tsinfo varchar2(5000); ---- /* i want to put tablespaces result to
>   this tsinfo */----
>
> CURSOR tbsp is select a.TABLESPACE_NAME as
>
> Tablespace,round((1-((a.BYTES-nvl(b.BYTES,0))/a.BYTES))*100,2)
>
> AS
>
> Percentages from (select TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES from
>
> sys.dba_data_files group by TABLESPACE_NAME) a,
>
> (select
>
> TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES from sys.dba_free_space
>
> group by
>
> TABLESPACE_NAME) b
>
> where
>
> a.TABLESPACE_NAME = b.TABLESPACE_NAME (+)
>
> order by ((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES) desc;
>
> BEGIN
>
> FOR each_data1 in tbsp
>
> LOOP
>
> FETCH tbsp INTO tsinfo; --- /* i want to put tablespaces result to
>   this tsinfo */ ---
>
> END LOOP;
>
> CLOSE tbsp;
>
> END;
>
> ----   /* get database lock status */ ----
>
> ELSIF var1 = 'b' THEN
>
> DECLARE
>
> lockinfo varchar2(1500);
>
> CURSOR lock_info is SELECT vh.sid locking_sid,
>
> vw.sid waiter_sid,
>
> vs.status status,
>
> vs.program program_holding,
>
> vsw.program program_waiting
>
> FROM v$lock vh,
>
> v$lock vw,
>
> v$session vs,
>
> v$session vsw
>
> WHERE(vh.id1, vh.id2) IN (SELECT id1, id2
>
> FROM v$lock
>
> WHERE request = 0
>
> INTERSECT
>
> SELECT id1, id2
>
> FROM v$lock
>
> WHERE lmode = 0)
>
> AND vh.id1 = vw.id1
>
> AND vh.id2 = vw.id2
>
> AND vh.request = 0
>
> AND vw.lmode = 0
>
> AND vh.sid = vs.sid
>
> AND vw.sid = vsw.sid;
>
> BEGIN
>
> FOR each_data in lock_info
>
> LOOP
>
> FETCH lock_info INTO lockinfo; -- i want to put database lock  result
>   to this tsinfo
>
> END LOOP;
>
> CLOSE lock_info;
>
> END;
>
> END IF;
>
> END;
>
> END;
>
> /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor tbsp selects 2 values:

```
CURSOR tbsp is 
  select a.TABLESPACE_NAME as Tablespace,
         round((1-((a.BYTES-nvl(b.BYTES,0))/a.BYTES))*100,2) AS Percentages
```

You need to `FETCH` into 2 variables (or into a record with 2 fields).

```
FETCH tbsp INTO tsinfo, percentage; -- You need to declare percentage
```

The formatting was so horrible that I decided not to scan the code for other errors.

Comment: @ Klas Lindbäck sir i want set the fetch values to out parapeter how can i do it?

Comment: You need to either add another out parameter or concatenate the two values (use `||` to concatenate strings).

Comment: Does It can convert into single varchar2 variable? For example convert the cursor to json string?